# R: How to use ifelse statement for a vector of characters

Tags: r, debugging, control-flow

I am trying to solve a quiz using R, but my code does not work properly. I tried debugging, but it seems that the ifelse statement fails to work at certain numbers that seem pretty random.

Here is the quiz: http://puzzles.nigelcoldwell.co.uk/six.htm

```
switches <- rep("off", 100)
for(i in 1:100){
  k <- c(seq(i, 100, i))
  ifelse(switches[k] == "off", switches[k] <- "on", switches[k] <- "off")
}
```

When I run this code, I get "on" for 14, 22, 26, 30, 34, etc in which I should have got "off." Is there a mistake in the way I applied ifelse statement to a vector with vectorized index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ifelse` syntax should be

```
switches <- rep("off", 100)
for(i in 1:100){
  k <-  seq(i, 100, i)
  switches[k] <- ifelse(switches[k] == "off",  "on", "off")
}
```

Comment: When I run my code, I get "on" for 1, 4, 9, 16, ... as they should be. The problem is that I also get "on" where I'm not supposed to. For example, 14 should be "off," but it's "on" in my code. I am wondering if there a logical flaw in my code or simply that I wrote in bad syntax.

Comment: @MinchulShin  By running the code in my post, it gives `[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100` for "on" values

Comment: @MinchulShin  Also, based on the output, this can be `switches[(1:10)^2] <- "on"`

Answer (score 1):

You have a binary problem. There is no reason to use `ifelse`. Work with logical values:

```
bulbs <- rep(FALSE, 100)
for (i in 1:100) bulbs[!((1:100) %% i)] <- !bulbs[!((1:100) %% i)]
which(bulbs)
#[1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```